# Async Producer/Consumer

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

I have a instance of a class that is accessed from several threads. This class take this calls and add a tuple into a database. I need this to be done in a serial manner, as due to some db constraints, parallel threads could result in an inconsistent database.

As I am new to parallelism and concurrency in C#, I did this:

```
private BlockingCollection<Task> _tasks = new BlockingCollection<Task>();

public void AddDData(string info)
{
    Task t = new Task(() => { InsertDataIntoBase(info); });
    _tasks.Add(t);
}

private void InsertWorker()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (!_tasks.IsCompleted)
        {
            Task t;
            if (_tasks.TryTake(out t))
            {
                t.Start();
                t.Wait();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The `AddDData` is the one who is called by multiple threads and `InsertDataIntoBase` is a very simple insert that should take few milliseconds.

The problem is that, for some reason that my lack of knowledge doesn't allow me to figure out, sometimes a task is been called twice! It always goes like this:

T1
T2
T3
T1 <- PK error.
T4
...

Did I understand `.Take()` completely wrong, am I missing something or my producer/ consumer implementation is really bad?

Best Regards,
Rafael

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, I made a quick sandbox test implementation with this architecture and as I was suspecting, it does not guarantee that a task will not be fired before the previous one finishes.

[image]

So the question remains: how to properly queue tasks and fire them sequentially?

**UPDATE 2:**

I simplified the code:

```
private BlockingCollection<Data> _tasks = new BlockingCollection<Data>();

public void AddDData(Data info)
{
    _tasks.Add(info);
}

private void InsertWorker()
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (!_tasks.IsCompleted)
        {
            Data info;
            if (_tasks.TryTake(out info))
            {
                InsertIntoDB(info);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note that I got rid of Tasks as I'm relying on synced InsertIntoDB call (as it is inside a loop), but still no luck... The generation is fine and I'm absolutely sure that only unique instances are going to the queue. But no matter I try, sometimes the same object is used twice.

Comment: How are you generating the primary key?

Comment: Actually I simplified the code shown here, as the data is not a string, but a hell of a complex object. The PK's are actually 2 object fields (a name string and a datetime value). I have no control over the database.

Comment: I think a simple `lock` would be enough to serialize the calls.

Comment: Just to be clear:  There is no way the data you are sending this is possibly bad -- correct?

Comment: Just a important comment: it doesn't matter much about the database, as the main problem is the fact that the task is been called twice, when it should be gone for good after been started. That made me think that maybe I have a architectural problem on this solution.

Comment: @I4V It would not help at all as a Lock here would totally spoil the overall performance. The idea behind using a BlockingCollection is to get rid of a Lock and allow a FIFO queue.

Comment: I'm not seeing how a task can get executed more than once here. Actually, I'm not even seeing the point of using tasks at all since they are all going to execute serially anyway. The `Task.Factory.StartNew` bit at least gets everything off the calling thread, but the other task stuff looks like a code smell.

Comment: @AustinSalonen It is not the data. I could replace the db insertion with a simple Console.Write(). As I said before, my main concern here is the fact that a task is been called twice...

Comment: @BrianGideon I agree on the code smell, but as I have no deeper experience with parallelism, I fear that I have no answer for you. About the Task, as I said, I need them to be executed serial, one call a time to the db. If I get rid of the task collection, chances are that sometimes concurrency will happen and db insert will fail due to pk constraints.

Comment: @RafaBorges FIFO queue or lock, you do the same and serialize db calls. I don't see any difference.

Comment: To confirm that you are indeed getting the same task to execute twice, write the PK and the TaskID (`Task.CurrentId`) to the command line and review the output.  I cannot reproduce this when starting 1M+ tasks...

Comment: Is there any reason not to just add the items directly to the blocking collection, and write the insert code directly in the Insert worker implementation rather than passing it in as a task?

Comment: @AustinSalonen Not only I did that as I also added a Random to a property in the object to track objects. Indeed it is firing twice... I have some updates and I will post them to the main post. Just in advance: this implementation is wrong. Now I have to find the right way to manage a queue like this.

Comment: @sga101 Yes: I must guarantee that inserts will be executed in the very same order as they come, once a time. Using a task is the only way I found that a .Wait() would be available.

Comment: From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287184.aspx): The order in which an item is removed depends on the type of collection used to create the BlockingCollection<T> instance. When you create a BlockingCollection<T> object, you can specify the type of collection to use. For example, you could specify a ConcurrentQueue object for first in, first out (FIFO) behavior. The default collection type for BlockingCollection<T> is ConcurrentQueue<T>.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have only one instance of this class?  Try making the collection static to check there really is only one.

Comment: It's not possible for `BlockingCollection` to give the same item twice. Either your producers are somehow producing duplicate items, or your `InsertIntoDB` method is somehow writing duplicate items. But I guarantee that `BlockingCollection` isn't somehow magically duplicating an item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
    private static BlockingCollection<string> _itemsToProcess = new BlockingCollection<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        InsertWorker();
        GenerateItems(10, 1000);
        _itemsToProcess.CompleteAdding();
    }

    private static void InsertWorker()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (!_itemsToProcess.IsCompleted)
            {
                string t;
                if (_itemsToProcess.TryTake(out t))
                {
                    // Do whatever needs doing here
                    // Order should be guaranteed since BlockingCollection 
                    // uses a ConcurrentQueue as a backing store by default.
                    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287184.aspx#remarksToggle
                    Console.WriteLine(t);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void GenerateItems(int count, int maxDelayInMs)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        string[] items = new string[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            items[i] = i.ToString();
        }

        // Simulate many threads adding items to the collection
        items
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)
            .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
            .Select((x) =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(r.Next(maxDelayInMs));
                _itemsToProcess.Add(x);
                return x;
            }).ToList();
    }
```

This does mean that the consumer is single threaded, but allows for multiple producer threads.

Comment: I tried it over 10000000 iterations without getting duplicates. Will think about it some more.

Comment: +1. Note that you can simplify your worker by replacing the `while (!IsCompleted)` and `TryTake` with a single `foreach (string t in _itemsToProcess.GetConsumingEnumerable())`. See [GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx).

Comment: @JimMischel I considered that, but the ordering is important here, and [this msdn document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460684.aspx) says that ordering is not guaranteed when using this method.

Comment: @sga101 After hours of debugging and logging, I found that the error was not in this part of the code, but in the database insert. Seems that there is a nasty bug caused by a race condition that I created with this code smell. As your code lead me to find this out, thumbs up for you and a thousand thanks!

Comment: @sga101: I assume you're talking about the line that says: "There is no guarantee that the items are enumerated in the same order in which they are added by the producer threads." Honestly, I don't know what that line is supposed to mean. I assure you that `GetConsumingEnumerable` *does* remove things in FIFO order. A look at the .NET Framework source code confirms that: `GetConsumingEnumerable` is just a bunch of `TryTake` calls in a loop. Items are definitely removed in the same order they're inserted.

Comment: @RafaBorges: See my previous comment, which I mistakenly posted to sga101.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment

> "I simplified the code shown here, as the data is not a string"

I assume that `info` parameter passed into AddDData is a mutable reference type. Make sure that the caller is not using the same `info` instance for multple calls since that reference is captured in Task lambda .

Comment: Yes, it is a mutable reference type and I will double check it (though I think this is not the problem). A race condition could potentially cause this behavior, but using a BlockingCollection as buffer wouldn't cut this risk?

Comment: Rafa Borges: I misread the code - there is no race conditions since it ensures that items get executed sequentially. It does not rule out possibility of the same item captured in different tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the trace that you provided the only logical possibility is that you have called `InsertWorker` twice (or more).  There are thus two background threads waiting for items to appear in the collection and occasionally they both manage to grab an item and begin executing it.